# Unable to find a DMN FEEL function in maven testing

Tags: maven, drools, dmn, kogito, feel-language

I have a simple DMN decision that counts an age from the date of birth:

```
years and months duration(date(DOB), today()).years
```

It's working fine in the KIE Sandbox but I'm not able to get it running from a `.scesim` file executed from maven (using `mvn test`). I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   #1: Failure reason: The decision "Age" has not been successfully evaluated: FEEL ERROR while evaluating literal expression 'years and months duration(date(DOB), today()).year... [string clipped after 50 chars, total length is 51]': Unable to find function 'date( lass org.kie.dmn.feel.runtime.functions.extended.DateFunctio )' (testAge)
[INFO]
```

I tried to follow https://blog.kie.org/2021/04/how-to-use-test-scenario-editor-to-test-your-dmn-asset-in-vscode.html but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm not able to get it running from a `.scesim` file

Likely, you haven't specified correctly one of the Input Data, so when the SceSim is run --in your case from Maven-- the evaluation fails because one of the specified input is *different* and wrong if compared to what you specified via the DMN JITRunner from the Sandbox.

I would expect the same behaviour if you run the same scesim for a JUnit activator and the IDE Test runner capabilities.

Best to do in this case is to provide a reproducer via the kogito-development mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/kogito-development

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I used `2001-10-10` in the scesim GIVEN section (making it a FEEL date type). The correct value is `"2001-10-10"` (a FEEL string) cause the [FEEL date function](https://kiegroup.github.io/dmn-feel-handbook/#date) accepts only a string as a param.